# Paritioning Scheme: Arch Linux server & laptop

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, tmp

**What would be a good partitioning scheme for an Arch Linux installation, *on a server and on a laptop?***

**My current basic scheme:**

```
/         [root]       ext4
/home                  ext4
swap
```

I know that the /var partition will contain many small files such as logs or pacman-related files, and the /tmp directory will be written to frequently as well.

**1)** Would I benefit from separate `"/var"` and/or `"/tmp"` partitions?

**2)** If so, what filesystems would you recommend on each of these partitions?

**3)** Is there a difference between the home server and the laptop? Should they have different partitioning schemes?

- The home server's system will be installed on a 80GB hard drive (it has an unrelated second 500GB HD).
- The laptop's system will be installed in a single 500GB hard drive, and the plan is to dedicate the remaining space to the `/home` partition.

**4)** How much space do you recommend dedicating to each partition (including root, and possibly /var & /tmp) on each system (*server/laptop*)? [note: I will be using LVM on both systems]

---

Some extra information: The server will run samba/rtorrent/ssh/LAMP/etc. and some backup mechanism. The laptop will be used as a PC, mainly internet & programming or other day-to-day software, but might run some servers for testing purposes (e.g LAMP).

Comment: Do your systems have UEFI?

Answer (score 3):

I've never understood the point of a separate `/var` partition in typical circumstances. On a special-purpose server, it might make sense to make some part of `/var` a different partition, e.g. separate `/var/mail` on a mail server, but otherwise just do the simple thing with 3 partitions: OS (`/`), data (`/home`) and swap.

Your own data should be in `/home`; for example your web root should be under `/home` (use symbolic links if necessary). This division has two major advantages:

- If you every want to reinstall the system, wipe the OS partition and retain the `/home` partition.
- Back up `/home` profusely. The OS partition can mostly be recovered by reinstalling as a last resort; the nonrecoverable bits are `/etc` and selected parts of `/var`, which you can do by `rsync`ing to a directory under `/home` and relying on the backups of `/home`.

Note that Grub legacy cannot boot from a LVM volume; you need [Grub2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2) (or to go through the hassle of a separate `/boot` partition).

Make `/tmp` a tmpfs filesystem (i.e. stored in virtual memory). See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/175861/ramdisk-ubuntu-10-04/175882#175882) for a write-up if Arch Linux doesn't do it by default.

Comment: Separate /var makes sense if you want a read-only /. (That is not en easy thing to do because in most distributions the /etc/init.d scripts or the services want to write there.)